# How can I detect values change in column for dynamic rows in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find a solution to dynamically change the line total column when quantity and unit price of the rows are change. How can I detect the change for each rows-this includes after cloning rows. Currently this is my html codes. I hope to dynamically change the values using jquery. I have been trying to research for a long time but I still couldn't figure it out.

Here an image to explain what I am referring:http://postimg.org/image/j9cb4r5rh/

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="col-sm-3">Item</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Item Name</th>
            <th class="col-sm-3">Description</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Unit Price</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Qty</th>
            <th class="col-sm-3">Line Total</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Stock Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr id='tableRow1' class='rows'>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox'/></td>  
            <td><input class="form-control"  disabled class="data_input" disabled/></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" class='inputPartNo' disabled></td>
            <td><textarea type='text' rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled /></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" ></td>
            <td> <input   class="form-control" ></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control" ></td>

            <td></td>
            <!--<td>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:9px 0 0 12px;"></span></td>-->
        </tr>

            <tr id='tableRow2' class='rows'>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox'/></td>
            <td><input class="form-control"  disabled class="data_input" disabled/></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" class='inputPartNo'disabled ></td>
            <td><textarea type='text' rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled /></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text"  class="form-control" ></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" ></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control" ></td>
            <td></td>

               <!--                <td>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="false" style="margin:9px 0 0 12px;"></span></td>-->
        </tr>

         <tr id='tableRow2' class='rows'>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox'/></td>
            <td><input class="form-control"  disabled class="data_input" disabled/></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" class='inputPartNo' disabled></td>
            <td><textarea type='text' rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled /></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text"  class="form-control" ></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" ></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control" ></td>
            <td></td>

                <!--                <td>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="false" style="margin:9px 0 0 12px;"></span></td>-->
        </tr>

         <tr id='tableRow2' class='rows'>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox'/></td>
            <td>                  
             <input class="form-control"  disabled class="data_input" disabled/>
            </td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" class='inputPartNo' disabled></td>
            <td><textarea type='text' rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled /></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text"  class="form-control" ></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" ></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control" ></td>
            <td></td>

    <!--                <td>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="false" style="margin:9px 0 0 12px;"></span></td>-->
        </tr>

         <tr id='tableRow2' class='rows'>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox' /></td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control"  disabled class="data_input" disabled/>
            </td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control" class='inputPartNo'class="data_input" disabled ></td>
            <td><textarea rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled class="data_input"/></textarea></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control" class="data_input" ></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control" ></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control" ></td>
            <td></td>

 <!--                <td>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="false" style="margin:9px 0 0 12px;"></span></td>-->
        </tr>



    </tbody>

</table>
```

Here is my jquery code as requested:

```
//Insert new rows after the last row in the table
    $("#add").click(function() 
    {
        var numRows = $('#getnumRows').val();
        alert(numRows);
        alert('triggered!');
        var selectlastRow=$('#mytable tbody>tr').eq(rowIndex);
        for (i=0; i < numRows; i++) 
            {                               
              $(selectlastRow).clone(true,true).insertAfter(selectlastRow);
              $(selectlastRow).addClass('rows');
              selectlastRow.find('td').children('select,input,textarea,input').val('');

            }
    });//end click tag
```

I have tried adding this each function.However it did not work out.

```
 $('.inputJobsheet>#mytable>tbody>.rows').each(function(index)){
alert(index);
});
```

Here's the codes that I have updated:

```
$('#mytable>tbody>tr>td').on('change', '.unitprice, .qty', function() {
  var $elem = event.target; //to get the element which triggered this event
  alert($elem);
  var $lineTotalElem = $elem.parent.find('.linetotal'); //get linetotal input val
  var qty = $elem.parent.find('.qty').val(); 
  var unitprice = $elem.parent.find('.unitprice').val() 
  if(qty !== undefined && unitprice !== undefined) {
  var total = qty * unitprice;
  if(total !== undefined || total > 0) {
   $lineTotalElem.val(total);
     }

       }
        });


<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="col-sm-3">Item</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Item Name</th>
            <th class="col-sm-3">Description</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Unit Price</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Qty</th>
            <th class="col-sm-3">Line Total</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Stock Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr id='tableRow1' class='rows'>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox'/></td>  
            <td><input class="form-control"  disabled  disabled/></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control"  disabled></td>
            <td><textarea type='text' rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled /></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control unitprice" ></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control qty" ></td>

            <td> <input  class="form-control linetotal" ></td>
            <td></td>
            <!--<td>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:9px 0 0 12px;"></span></td>-->
        </tr>

            <tr id='tableRow2' class='rows'>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox'/></td>
            <td><input class="form-control"  disabled  disabled/></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled ></td>
            <td><textarea type='text' rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled /></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text"  class="form-control unitprice" ></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control qty" ></td>

            <td> <input  class="form-control linetotal" ></td>
            <td></td>


        </tr>

         <tr id='tableRow2' class='rows'>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox'/></td>
            <td><input class="form-control"   disabled/></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></td>
            <td><textarea type='text' rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled /></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text"  class="form-control unitprice" ></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control qty" ></td>

            <td> <input  class="form-control linetotal" ></td>
            <td></td>


        </tr>

         <tr id='tableRow2' class='rows'>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox'/></td>
            <td>                  
             <input class="form-control"  disabled disabled/>
            </td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control"  disabled></td>
            <td><textarea type='text' rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled /></textarea></td>
            <td> <input type="text"  class="form-control unitprice" ></td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control qty" ></td>

            <td> <input  class="form-control linetotal" ></td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>

         <tr id='tableRow2' class='rows'>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox' /></td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control"  disabled  disabled/>
            </td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control" disabled ></td>
            <td><textarea rows="4" cols="40" class="form-control" disabled/></textarea></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control unitprice"   ></td>
            <td> <input  class="form-control qty" ></td>

            <td> <input  class="form-control linetotal" ></td>
            <td></td>


        </tr>



    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Please post your javascript/ jquery code

Comment: Please update your code so that we can see what's happening?

Comment: Okay,sorry for the trouble! Let me update the code again! :)

Comment: I have just updated the code here!

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching the `onchange` event to the row elements like this,

```
$('#mytable').on('change', '.unitprice, .qty', function() {
  /* do your calculation here */
});
```

This will attach the onchange event to the current as well as future elements also. It is called **Delegated events**, and have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. Also an event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody) as in normal event handlers the event is bind to each row.

**Edit**

You have added many `class` attributes, which is not necessary to add multiple classes. You can add multiple classes in same attribute like `class="class1 class2 class3"`.

Add class `unitprice` to the input elements which are in the same column as the title Unit Price. Same for class `qty` under title Qty and `linetotal` under Line Total. Now as you want to calculate the Line Total from Unit Price and Qty, you have to add onchange event to the both input elements with classes `unitprice` and `qty`. So the above `onchange` event handler can be used as,

```
$('#mytable').on('change', '.unitprice, .qty', function(event) {
  var $elem = event.target; //to get the element which triggered this event
  var $lineTotalElem = $elem.parent.find('.linetotal'); //get linetotal input val
  var qty = $elem.parent.find('.qty').val(); 
  var unitprice = $elem.parent.find('.unitprice').val() 
  if(qty !== undefined && unitprice !== undefined) {
    var total = qty * unitprice;
    if(total !== undefined || total > 0) {
      $lineTotalElem.val(total);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it was obviously incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now it is much clearer! However I am still unable to select the class selectors .unitprice, .qty after adding these two classes in my html.In addition to your jquery codes. Hmm..? :/

Comment: Where exactly did you add them in your html?

Comment: I place the classes in the input tags after the td tags.

Comment: Yup, I looked into that before you updated the reply. I have changed it but I am still unable to select class  from the selectors that I have just assign them to which are namely unitprice and qty to try out the jquery codes that you have posted.